# How to check current date and move to next date

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a python issue which I cannot seem to understand. Not sure if I need to use if statements but because I'm new to python, I'm not actually sure how to code this little issue.

Virtually this is the issue I have. For the departure calendar, I want python to be able to do the following:

- View 'Your date'. If there's a flight (doesn't matter if lowfare or normal), click it. If not then move onto the next available date that does have a flight and click that.
- Will need to be able to move to the next month if no date is available in the current month (I have an example code for this).

For the return calendar, I want it to do the same thing but ensure it selects a date at least 7 days after the selected departure date.

That's virtually my question, how to do that?

Below is the html of the depature calendar (return calendar is exactly the same except it's inboundsearchresults rather than outbound search results):

Below I have a sample code which works when selecting from an ordinary date picker (this is used in the page before the url) if you want to use that template and manipulate it:

```
# select depart date
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-date-selector")
actions.move_to_element(datepicker).click().perform()

# find the calendar, month and year picker and the current date
calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("departureDateContainer")
month_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month"))
year_picker = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
current_date = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-current-day")

# printing out current date
month = month_picker.first_selected_option.text
year = year_picker.first_selected_option.text
print("Current departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=current_date.text, month=month, year=year))

# see if we have an available date in this month
try:
    next_available_date = current_date.find_element_by_xpath("following::td[@data-handler='selectDay' and ancestor::div/@id='departureDateContainer']")
    print("Found an available departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
    next_available_date.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
# looping over until the next available date found
        while True:
# click next, if not found, select the next year
            try:
                calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next").click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
# select next year
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year"))
                year.select_by_visible_text(str(int(year.first_selected_option.text) + 1))

# reporting current processed month and year
                month = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-month")).first_selected_option.text
                year = Select(calendar.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-year")).first_selected_option.text
                print("Processing {month} {year}".format(month=month, year=year))

            try:
                next_available_date = calendar.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-handler='selectDay']")
                print("Found an available departure date: {day} {month} {year}".format(day=next_available_date.text, month=month, year=year))
                next_available_date.click()
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to define a reusable function - calling it `select_date()` that receives a "calendar" WebElement and an optional minimum date. This function would first look for the `Your date` in the calendar and if it is there and it is more than minimum (if given) click it and return the date. If there is no `Your date`, look for the available "flight" days and, if minimum date is given and the date is more than or equal to it, click it and return the date.

Working implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def select_date(calendar, mininum_date=None):
    try:
        # check if "Your Date" is there
        your_date_elm = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("your-date")

        your_date = your_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date")
        print("Found 'Your Date': " + your_date)
        your_date_elm.click()

        # check if your_date against the minimum date if given
        your_date = datetime.strptime(your_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if mininum_date and your_date < mininum_date:
            raise NoSuchElementException("Minimum date violation")
        return your_date
    except NoSuchElementException:
        flight_date = None
        flight_date_elm = None
        while True:
            print("Processing " + calendar.find_element_by_css_selector("div.subheader > p").text)

            try:
                if mininum_date:
                    flight_date_elms = calendar.find_elements_by_class_name("flights")
                    flight_date_elm = next(flight_date_elm for flight_date_elm in flight_date_elms
                                           if datetime.strptime(flight_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date"), "%Y-%m-%d") >= mininum_date)
                else:
                    flight_date_elm = calendar.find_element_by_class_name("flights")
            except (StopIteration, NoSuchElementException):
                calendar.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Next month").click()

            # if found - print out the date, click and exit the loop
            if flight_date_elm:
                flight_date = flight_date_elm.get_attribute("data-date")
                print("Found 'Flight Date': " + flight_date)
                flight_date_elm.click()
                break

        return datetime.strptime(flight_date, "%Y-%m-%d")


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.jet2.com/cheap-flights/leeds-bradford/antalya/2016-03-01/2016-04-12?adults=2&children=2&infants=1&childages=4%2c6")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# get the outbound date
outbound = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "outboundsearchresults")))
outbound_date = select_date(outbound)

# get the inbound date
inbound = driver.find_element_by_id("inboundsearchresults")
inbound_minimum_date = outbound_date + timedelta(days=7)
inbound_date = select_date(inbound, mininum_date=inbound_minimum_date)

print(outbound_date, inbound_date)

driver.close()
```

For the provided in the question URL, it prints:

```
Processing March 2016
Found 'Flight Date': 2016-03-28

Processing April 2016
Found 'Flight Date': 2016-04-04

2016-03-28 00:00:00 2016-04-04 00:00:00
```

The two dates printed at the end are the departure and the return dates.

Let me know if you need any clarifications and hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, I have a lot to learn in a short time but with your script, I can use it to help manipulate other scripts I have. There is one more barrier later on I have to deal with and may need to ask for your help later but in mean time, thank you very much :)

Comment: @BruceyBandit sure, glad to see you are going deeper into test automation. Let me know if you need further help.